# How to solve Eslint error in the build process of Next.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js, build, eslint

Build was executed using the **`npm run build`** command in **`Next.js.`**

As a result, the following Eslint error occurred:

```
info  - Checking validity of types
warn  - The Next.js plugin was not detected in your ESLint configuration. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#migrating-existing-config

Failed to compile.

./pages/hashtag/[tag].js
Error: Parsing error: require() of ES Module C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Desktop\Recipe.io\prepare\front\node_modules\eslint-scope\lib\definition.js from C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Desktop\Recipe.io\prepare\front\node_modules\babel-eslint\lib\require-from-eslint.js not supported.
Instead change the require of definition.js in C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Desktop\Recipe.io\prepare\front\node_modules\babel-eslint\lib\require-from-eslint.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

./pages/index.js
Error: Parsing error: require() of ES Module C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Desktop\Recipe.io\prepare\front\node_modules\eslint-scope\lib\definition.js from C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Desktop\Recipe.io\prepare\front\node_modules\babel-eslint\lib\require-from-eslint.js not supported.
Instead change the require of definition.js in C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Desktop\Recipe.io\prepare\front\node_modules\babel-eslint\lib\require-from-eslint.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
                                      : 
                                      :
               All components and pages get the same error as above
```

I've tried to solve the error, but I can't find a way, so I'm asking.

How can I solve the above error so that the build can be done normally?

Currently, the **`package.json`** and **`.eslintrc`** files in my project are as follows.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.26.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.10",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0"
  }
}
```

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "airbnb"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "import",
    "react-hooks"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control": "off",
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": "off",
    "no-console": "off",
    "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
    "react/forbid-prop-types": "off",
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": "off",
    "object-curly-newline": "off",
    "linebreak-style": "off",
    "no-param-reassign": "off"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

to solve that error follow this steps:

1. install elsint extension in vscode
2. hover your mouse cursor in error or red filed in code.
3. press ctrl + space then you will get options to fix this error
4. click in fix this error.
5. then again you see list of options
6. click one of them or try each to remove that error

Comment: Thank you for answer.
But that answer doesn't seem to be a way to solve the build process error described in the question, is that correct?